# Give message to user "Product already installed. Uninstall and install new one." using installshield

Tags: upgrade, installshield, uninstallation

I have a product(setup.exe) version 1.1.3 already in use and I am developing new version 1.2.1 using Installshield. If user clicks on setup.exe (1.2.1) and if system has 1.1.3 already installed then it should give error message that "product already installed. Uninstall and install new one" using Installshield.

I tried using media->upgrades-> add major/minor upgrade property but didn't help.
I am using InstallShield 2016SP1.

Comment: This is not user friendly at all to produce such errors, instead installation process 1.2.1 needs to perform major upgrade, if by your logic the 1.1.3 version must be completely uninstalled. More about difference: [Major Upgrade vs. Minor Upgrade vs. Small Update](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/MajorMinorSmall.htm). From the same document to perform major upgrade you need to change: package and product code + version number.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov. Agreed that logically I should go for minor upgrade but then I can not change requirement. I can just implement it.

Comment: #Solution worked for me#
Installshield -> Media -> Upgrades -> "Upgrade Windows Installer Setup"

on Right side panel,

1) On Common tab, select "disable" in first block

2) On Advanced tab, select "Disable" value for On Upgrade property.

This fixed my issue. Hope this will help